# Post callbacks to a task queue using boost::bind

Tags: c++, boost-bind, boost-function, boost-phoenix, boost-lambda

Suppose I have a function called `subscribe()` that takes a callback handler, which will be called when the event is triggered.

Now, I have another version, called `subscribe2()`. Everything is the same except that, when triggered, it needs to post it to an event queue. It is implemented using the original `subscribe()`, with a helper funciton called `helper()`. All it does is to bind the original handler and whatever additional arguments into a functor, and call `postToEventQueue()`.

Now, I wonder if there's a way to eliminate the helper function, so that in `subsribe2()`, I can somehow package the `postToTaskQueue()` function and the original callback handler directly, and pass it to `subscribe()`. The reason is that I have a lot of different handler types, and it is tedious and tiring to introduce helper function all over the place. Afterall, boost::bind is supposed to return a new function given the original function, right? I am trying to generate the helper function directly with boost::bind.

One attempt is to say

```
subscribe(boost::bind(boost::bind(postToTaskQueue, boost::bind(_1, _2)), cb, _1));
```

in `subscribe2()`, but it doesn't work. Is it possible at all?

Please see detailed example code below. Thanks!

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <iostream>

typedef boost::function<void(int)> SomeCallback;
typedef boost::function<void()> Task;

void handler(int i){
 std::cout << "i=" << i <<std::endl;
}

void subscribe(SomeCallback cb)
{
  cb(100);  //just invoke the callback for simplicity
}

void postToTaskQueue(Task t)
{
   t();  // just invoke the task for simplicity
}

void helper(SomeCallback cb, int i)
{
   Task t = boost::bind(cb, i);
   postToTaskQueue(t);
}

void subscribe2(SomeCallback cb)
{
  subscribe(boost::bind(helper, cb, _1));

  // this does not work..
  // subscribe(boost::bind(boost::bind(postToTaskQueue, boost::bind(_1, _2)), cb, _1)); 
}
int main()
{
  subscribe(boost::bind(handler, _1));
  subscribe2(boost::bind(handler, _1));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I have no answer. However, I've played with this for over an hour:

- `boost::bind`
- `boost::apply<>`
- `boost::protect`

Maybe, just maybe, a more experienced boost developer could take it from here:

```
void subscribe2(SomeCallback cb)
{
    using boost::bind;
    using boost::protect;
    using boost::apply;

    bind(cb, 41)(); // OK of course
    postToTaskQueue(bind(cb, 46)); // also fine
    bind(postToTaskQueue, protect(bind(cb, 146)))(); // boost::protect to the rescue

    postToTaskQueue(bind(apply<void>(), cb, 47));
    bind(postToTaskQueue, protect(bind(apply<void>(), cb, 147)))();
```

The above prints

```
i=41
i=46
i=146
i=47
i=147
```

But, sadly, I can't seem to make this this thing parameterizing (as suggested should work in [the documentation on composition using Nested Binds](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/bind/bind.html#nested_binds)):

```
    // but sadly, this appears to not work ...
    auto hmm = bind(postToTaskQueue, bind(apply<void>(), cb, _1));
    hmm(997); // FAIL
}
```

Here's a fully compiled demo showing the state of affairs: **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e58e82e55df7e03)**

```
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/protect.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/apply.hpp>
#include <iostream>

typedef boost::function<void(int)> SomeCallback;
typedef boost::function<void()>    Task;

void handler(int i){
    std::cout << "i=" << i <<std::endl;
}

void subscribe(SomeCallback cb)
{
    cb(100);  //just invoke the callback for simplicity
}

void postToTaskQueue(Task t)
{
    t();  // just invoke the task for simplicity
}

void helper(SomeCallback cb, int i)
{
    postToTaskQueue(boost::bind(cb, i));
}

void subscribe2(SomeCallback cb)
{
    using boost::bind;
    using boost::protect;
    using boost::apply;

    bind(cb, 41)(); // OK of course
    postToTaskQueue(bind(cb, 46)); // also find
    bind(postToTaskQueue, protect(bind(cb, 146)))(); // boost::protect to the rescue

    postToTaskQueue(bind(apply<void>(), cb, 47));
    bind(postToTaskQueue, protect(bind(apply<void>(), cb, 147)))();

    // but sadly, this appears to not work ...
    auto hmm = bind(postToTaskQueue, bind(apply<void>(), cb, _1));
    //hmm(997); // FAIL
}
int main()
{
    subscribe (boost::bind(handler, _1));
    subscribe2(boost::bind(handler, _1));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are binding a function (`helper`) that itself does a bind. That mean you are (indirectly) binding `bind` itself. This is the key insight. The solution is to write a little `bind` function object wrapper that can itself be bound. Here's what my solution looks like:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/phoenix/core/argument.hpp>
using boost::phoenix::placeholders::_1;
typedef boost::function<void(int)> SomeCallback;
typedef boost::function<void()> Task;

struct bind_t
{
    template<typename Sig>
    struct result;

    template<typename This, typename ...A>
    struct result<This(A...)>
    {
        typedef decltype(boost::phoenix::bind(std::declval<A>()...)) type;
    };

    template<typename ...A>
    auto operator()(A &&...a) const -> decltype(boost::phoenix::bind(std::forward<A>(a)...))
    {
        return boost::phoenix::bind(std::forward<A>(a)...);
    }
};

bind_t const bind = {};

void handler(int i)
{
    std::cout << "i=" << i <<std::endl;
}

void subscribe(SomeCallback cb)
{
    cb(100);  //just invoke the callback for simplicity
}

void postToTaskQueue(Task t)
{
    t();  // just invoke the task for simplicity
}

void subscribe2(SomeCallback cb)
{
    subscribe(bind(postToTaskQueue, bind(bind, cb, _1)));
}

int main()
{
    subscribe(::bind(handler, _1));
    subscribe2(::bind(handler, _1));
}
```

I switched to Phoenix's `bind` because it lets you bind polymorphic function objects (which `bind` above is).

This solution requires `decltype`. It also uses variadics, but that can be faked with overloads up to N arguments. Rvalue refs are also a convenience that can be done without with a little more work.

Comment: How did I miss this answer.  I like your explanation (as so often), and though it still requires "helpers" at least it uses only generic,  reusable ones.