# How to use std::function in a qi symbol table

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, symbols, qi

I have the following code. This code shall parse two int and return the result of a comparison as a bool.
For compare, I use the qi::symbol table. But, unfortunately, it does not compile. Any idea what goes wrong?

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
int main(sint32 argc, char **argv)
{
  boost::spirit::qi::symbols<char, std::function<bool(int, int)>> sym;
  sym.add
  ("==", [](int v1, int v2) {return v1 == v2; })
  ("!=", [](int v1, int v2) {return v1 != v2; });
  bool result;
  std::string s("1==2");
  namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
  qi::phrase_parse(s.begin(), s.end(), (qi::int_ >> sym >> qi::int_)[qi::_val = boost::bind(qi::_2, qi::_1, qi::_3)], qi::space, result);
}
```

Comment: I assume there is an error message.  While long, it is worth quoting.  Do a `>` then indent each line 5 spaces after the `>` to get "quoted code", which I find works well for error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, don't use `boost::bind` in a semantic action.

Semantic actions need to be Phoenix Actors. In other words, deferred or lazy function objects.

The way to get that would normally be using `boost::phoenix::bind`, but in this case you lose out: the bind doesn't expect a placeholder and doesn't know how to bind to it.

Instead, make the symbol table *expose* deferred functions. But then you need advanced wizardry to protect the inner bind from the outer ones: [Post callbacks to a task queue using boost::bind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18680114/post-callbacks-to-a-task-queue-using-boostbind/19101935#19101935)

Instead I suggest doing the entire evaluation in a custom lazy action:

```
auto bin_eval = [](auto const& lhs, auto const& op, auto const& rhs) {
    return op(lhs, rhs);
};
```

And then

```
   (qi::int_ >> sym >> qi::int_)
        [qi::_val = px::bind(bin_eval, _1, _2, _3)],
```

However, that's not all yet. Your sample was likely oversimplified, as it couldn't even compile with correct semantic action. Instead you need to suppress attribute propagation, which only happens when you add a semantic action to a rule:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ae170fca624ae6a1)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace px = boost::phoenix;

int main() {
    qi::symbols<char, std::function<bool(int, int)>> sym;
    sym.add
        ("==", [](int v1, int v2) {return v1 == v2; })
        ("!=", [](int v1, int v2) {return v1 != v2; });

    using namespace qi::labels;
    bool result;
    auto bin_eval = [](auto const& lhs, auto const& op, auto const& rhs) {
        return op(lhs, rhs);
    };

    qi::rule<std::string::const_iterator, bool(), qi::space_type> rule;
    rule = (qi::int_ >> sym >> qi::int_)
            [qi::_val = px::bind(bin_eval, _1, _2, _3)];

    for (std::string const s : {"1==2", "1!=2" }) {
        std::cout << std::quoted(s) << " -> ";

        if (qi::phrase_parse(s.begin(), s.end(), rule, qi::space, result)) {
            std::cout << "result: " << std::boolalpha << result << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "parse failed\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
"1==2" -> result: false
"1!=2" -> result: true
```

### Prettier?

For bonus points, lift to a proper Phoenix Function:

```
struct bin_eval_t {
    template <typename T, typename U, typename V>
    auto operator()(T const& lhs, U const& op, V const& rhs) const {
        return op(lhs, rhs);
    }
};

// ...
px::function<bin_eval_t> bin_eval;

// ...
rule = (qi::int_ >> sym >> qi::int_)
        [qi::_val = bin_eval(_1, _2, _3)];
```

### Simpler?

You can replace the lambdas with std functional:

```
sym.add
    ("==", std::equal_to<>{})
    ("!=", std::not_equal_to<>{});
```

Or if you don't have c++14

```
sym.add
    ("==", std::equal_to<int>{})
    ("!=", std::not_equal_to<int>{});
```

### Much More?

If you want heterogeneous evaluations (not just boolean predicates), unary operators, precedence, associativity, look at some examples I made on this site.

Usually they separate the evaluation stage from the parsing stage:

- this is the most recent, most complete https://github.com/sehe/qi-extended-parser-evaluator (made for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60845800/how-to-combine-skipping-and-non-skipping-lexeme-rules) as discussed in detail [in this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/210289/2020/3/25)
- many simpler examples [on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a85371%20qi%20eval)

However, if you want you can indeed combine parsing with evaluation. In that case it makes sense to simplify everything to be directly in the semantic actions:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fbe8ab0fd119ba54)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>
#include <iomanip>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main() {
    using namespace qi::labels;

    for (std::string const s : {"1==2", "1!=2" }) {
        std::cout << std::quoted(s) << " -> ";

        bool result;
        if (qi::phrase_parse(s.begin(), s.end(), 
            qi::int_ >> (
                "==" >> qi::int_ [ _val = (_val == _1) ]
              | "!=" >> qi::int_ [ _val = (_val != _1) ]
            ),
            qi::space,
            result))
        {
            std::cout << "result: " << std::boolalpha << result << "\n";
        } else {
            std::cout << "parse failed\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
"1==2" -> result: false
"1!=2" -> result: true
```